# Ford dealer over filling engine oil

Tags: ford

I did a regular service for my ford explorer at 35500 km in ford dealer, next service due at 45500 km .the car got shipped and used 5 months later. I drove the car for about 3000 km , at 38500 km a low engine oil pressure warning popped up, I found that Ford dealer put 1.3 US gallon more then the recommended amount. Engine can start, cracking noise and RPM fluctuating. Ford refused to admit, knowing that there is no reason for me to change the engine oil as the next service is not yet due. How can i proceed from here?

Comment: What engine? petrol/gasoline or diesel?

Comment: 1.3 **gallons** more engine oil? That doesn't sound physically possible, how did you measure this?

Comment: Just to clarify; the vehicle operated with no apparent issues for 3000 km from when it was serviced to when you saw the oil pressure warning? What does/did the dipstick say when the warning light came on? Did it show low or high? What does it show currently? If the dipstick currently reads high, change the oil and put the appropriate amount in.

Comment: Like GdD I'm inclined to think that 1.3 US Gal extra figure isn't entirely accurate - that would be nearly **double** the oil capacity (assuming it was the 3.5 V6) even if they were able to physically fit that much in the engine you'd know about it long before driving 3000km.

Comment: My apologies “ Solar Mike” , “ GdD “ & “ motosubatsu “ for the late reply, did not get any notification of your valuable comments and i was following up with Ford for a any positive response.

Comment: Solar Mike , it’s 3.5L petrol engine.

Comment: Tim Nevins, no single indication that i am running with an overfilled oil engine until the moment the warning popped up , and since it’s related to oil pressure , i took it for oil check and/or change ( even though i am at 30% from oil change due milage , run for 3000 km and remaining 7000 km for oil change).

Comment: Tim Nevin , the dipstick shows high, the oil was drained using oil extractor machine, the machine glass container was filled ( its limit 10 liters ), same got released in the lower metal container and another 1 liter was extracted, the appropriate oil amount and grading was put in the engine, but apparently it was too late as the engine got damaged , diagnostic codes P0420, P0012, P0015, P0017, the whole process of oil suction was video recorded and official certificate provided by the oil company.

Comment: motosubatsu, as i shared with Tim (see above) , the extracted amount was slightly lower then double , NO indication at all , as in at all, until the low engine oil pressure warning popped up at the dashboard.

Comment: GdD, the engine oil was extracted using suction machine, the upper glass container capacity of the machine is 10 liters , it got full, and another 1 liter was suctioned.